# How to load an image for prediction from buffer?

Tags: python, api, tensorflow

I made a deep learning model and I want to make an api for consume the model, but I don't want to save the image on the server and later load the image to the model. I want to receive the buffer of the image and load the image from the buffer. Can I do that? and how do it? The model is an CNN for image classifier in keras.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pillow and `requests` for this:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests

img = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
```